# how to position logo image on left hand side of material UI app bar with no space

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So I have a material UI app bar that I am using for my navigation bar so I have my nav items which are my routes which I pass down as props and their onClick handlers but the issue I am facing is with the logo image on the left hand side of the page there seems to be a large spacing between it and the left hand side of the page as you can see in the image but I cannot figure out how to get the image tightly bound to the left hand side of the nav bar with only a small amount of space between the image and the edge. Does anyone know what styling I need to apply or override to achieve this? It moves more closer to the edge when I add a negative margin but that of course isn't good for responsiveness surely there is another way?

**image of the current nav bar with the space to the left hand side of the image:**

[image]

**here is the current component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import AdbIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Adb';
import logoSVG from '../assets/logo/logo.svg'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const pages = ['Products', 'Pricing', 'Blog'];
const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Dashboard', 'Logout'];



function MaterialNavBar({routes, handleNavigationClick}) {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState(null);



  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };
  // nav bar color #EBF0EE
  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" sx={{backgroundColor: ''}} iconElementLeft>   
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
        
        <img 
          src={logoSVG} 
          alt="Logo" 
          className="logo" 
          style={{
            marginLeft: '-100px', // Adjust as needed
          }}
          />
        
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="#app-bar-with-responsive-menu"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="#app-bar-with-responsive-menu"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex',  }, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
                <Link key={index}
                    to={route.path}
                    onClick={handleNavigationClick}
                    sx={{
                        marginRight: '10px',
                        textDecoration: 'none', // Remove default underline
                        color: 'inherit', // Inherit text color
                        '&:hover': {
                        textDecoration: 'underline', // Add underline on hover
                        color: '#D6A82F', // Change color on hover
                            },
                        }}>
                    {route.label}
                </Link>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
export default MaterialNavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` is currently under a `<Container>` component which adds horizontal paddings, you have either to remove that component:

```
    <AppBar position="fixed" sx={{backgroundColor: ''}} iconElementLeft>   
  
    <Toolbar disableGutters>
    
    <img 
      src={logoSVG} 
      alt="Logo" 
      className="logo" 
      />

   // remaining code ...
```

or to pull out your image from that container:

```
    <AppBar position="fixed" sx={{backgroundColor: ''}} iconElementLeft>   
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
      </Container>
      <img 
        src={logoSVG} 
        alt="Logo" 
        className="logo" 
      />
  // remaining code ...
```